# pg_dump version mismatch on Debian

Tags: debian, postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL on Debian Unstable/Sid.  I've got the current versions (9.1) of `postgresql`, `postgresql-client`, `postgresql-client-common` (143) installed.

The problem I'm having is trying to run `pg_dump`.  I'm getting this error:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.1.9; pg_dump version: 9.0.6
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get a newer version of `pg_dump`.  It seems to be coming from the `postgresql-client-common` package, and I've trying running `apt-get --reinstall` on it, but that didn't get me a newer version of pg_dump.

How do I work around this?  Or where can I find a package with a newer version of `pg_dump`?

Comment: You realize that this is par for the course since you're running Debian Sid? It's unstable. What does `which pg_dump` show you? Just to confirm that it's in fact the packaged version and not some other one.

Comment: Yup, I checked that.  It's showing `/usr/bin/pg_dump`, and `dpkg -S /usr/bin/pg_dump` gives me `postgresql-client-common: /usr/bin/pg_dump`.

Comment: Check out my answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of options.

#### Download .deb 9.1 from the Postgres site

Take a look at this page titled: [Linux downloads (Debian) - PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/). You can either download an updated .deb from the site directly, or re-point to their repository, and do a command like this:

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

#### Debian backports

You may be able to find specific versions here, http://backports.debian.org/.

#### Use a generic version

You can [download a binary build of PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/) and put install it in your home directory or `/opt` for example.

#### Download one of the pre-builds for enterprise use

I don't have much experience with these but you may be able to [download one of these](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) similar to a generic version and use the client from it's installation, as is, do dump your database.

#### Cross distribution packages

You can [download packages](http://www.openscg.com/se/postgresql/packages.jsp) which have been built so that they're distribution agnostic. I just downloaded the 9.1.9 version and it does include the `pg_dump` tool.

The software is provided as either .rpm or .deb and installs to `/opt/postgres/9.1`. Specifically the `pg_dump` tool is provided here: `/opt/postgres/9.1/bin/pg_dump`.

Comment: The version of PostgreSQL isn't really the problem.  It's the version of `pg_dump` that's old and incompatible.  Is there someplace I can find specifically that?

Comment: I think it's bundled in with these packages. I would just download one of the pre-builds for the specific version and use the `pg_dump` command out of there. They shouldn't have to be installed, just untarred into a directory. You might have to set an environment variable to point to a library directory but it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had two sets of databases some running on the old version of Postgresql 8.4 and other running on version 9.1. What I did was to locate `pg_dump` in Linux machine using the `locate` command below

```
$ locate pg_dump

/usr/bin/pg_dump
/usr/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_dumpall
```

Since the default `/usr/bin/pg_dump` is for Postgresql version 8.4, I just specified `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_dump` from command line when dumping from 9.1 databases which runs on a different port and it worked.

```
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_dump -p 5434
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option, that may be suitable for you, is to uninstall the old parallel version:

on debian/ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-8.4
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-client-8.4
```

That preserves the later version (e.g 9.1) removing only the older 8.4 client and server libs.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, you can also tell `pg_dump` and other commands, which version to use via the `cluster` option. For instance,

```
$pg_dump --cluster 9.1/main
```

will target the 9.1 version.

Note that this makes use of `pg_wrapper`, which comes with [`postgresql-common`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-common) and works on **Ubuntu** (Debian). Also note that the cluster (`main` in the example) might be different in your setting.

More information on `pg_wrapper` can be found in this [DBA answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21007).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today and Erick's answer seems to be most accurate.  The problem is likely that you have different versions of the postgresql-client and pg_dump is just using the oldest client.

You can resolve this by using the full path as he described, but I found an easier solution to be to remove the postgresql-client-common package (which removes all clients), then reinstall postgresql-client-9.3.  This leaves you with only the latest versions of pg_dump which is probably want you want.